# Trying to Increase Heap Size of Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

To increase my heap size, I created a new file-studio.exe.vmoptions at

`[Directory]/Users/[User Name]/Androidstudio2.1/studio.exe.vmoptions`

This is the content of that file:

```
-server
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da   -Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.1
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

I don't know if the heap size increased or not, but now Android Studio isn't working: it doesn't open now.

What changes should I make to this file or is it a bug in Android Studio?

Comment: I think you modified the JVM that Android Studio runs in. Not the emulator.

Answer (score 4):

First revert back all the changes you've made and then use AVD Manager to increase heap size of your emulator.

- Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager
- Select a virtual device and click on its pencil icon (edit)
- Click on <kbd>Show Advanced Settings</kbd>
- Under "Memory and Storage" change "VM Heap"

[image]